# Find set with specific element in set of sets in Python

Tags: python, set

I have the following set of sets in Python (no element could occure more than one anywhere):

```
set_of_sets = {frozenset({"01", "02", "03"}),
               frozenset({"04", "05", "06"}),
               frozenset({"07", "08"}),
               frozenset({"09", "10"}),
               frozenset({"11"}),
               frozenset({"12"}),
               frozenset({"13"}),
               frozenset({"14"}),
               frozenset({"15"})}
```

Now, I want to figure out if any requested element is in the set of sets, and if so, what is the specific set (get all the elements of this set). I have got here so far:

```
if any("001" in subset for subset in set_of_sets):
   print("Present:")
else:
   print("Not Present")
```

But this doesn't give the found set itself. I could go for this option:

```
for subset in set_of_sets:
    if "01" in subset:
        print(subset)
```

but this doesn't handle the possibility of not founding the element in question, and given the nature of unique occurence of elements, this full iteration over the subsets is somewhat wasteful (in case we found the subset).

Comment: In the second example, break out of the loop if you find the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write for example:

```
next(s for s in set_of_sets if "08" in s)
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if the item is not found.

As pointed out by Mark in a comment, the optional default argument for `next` could be used to avoid the exception if you want a result like None instead:

```
next((s for s in set_of_sets if "08" in s), None)
```

Comment: You might consider passing the second argument for `next()` so you don't raise the exception: `next((s for s in set_of_sets if "08" in s), None)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to just return a list of found items, since you're only going to find one, you can simply print found[0]. An empty list will hit the else block and print 'Not Present'

```py
found = [subset for subset in set_of_sets if "13" in subset]

if found:
    print("Present:")
    print(found[0])
else:
   print("Not Present")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dict with the numbers as keys and the sets as values, but we can also improve yours:

> this full iteration over the subsets is somewhat wasteful

So use `break`:

```
for subset in set_of_sets:
    if "01" in subset:
        print(subset)
        break
```

> this doesn't handle the possibility of not founding the element in question

So use `else`:

```
for subset in set_of_sets:
    if "01" in subset:
        print(subset)
        break
else:
    print("Not Present")
```